# COLS vs getmaxx in ncurses

Tags: ncurses

Tinkering with ncurses; can't seem to find why I would want to use getmaxyx() instead of LINES and COLS, or vice-versa.

It seems to me that LINES and COLS is already initialized by initscr(), so why would I want to go through the additional step of calling getmaxyx() and setting new variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`LINES`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_variables.3x.html#h3-LINES) and [`COLS`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_variables.3x.html#h3-COLS) are the size of the *screen*, while [`getmaxyx`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getyx.3x.html) gives the size of a *window*.  curses applications can have several windows (and rarely more than one screen).

Comment: Ah, I never caught onto that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Looking more into it, I see that for the initial "stdscr" window that is created by the initscr() call, the LINES and COLS variables are equivalent to the X and Y of getmaxyx(), even after resizing the screen/window.

So as long as you're dealing only with one window (the default window created by the initscr() call), I think you can use either method. But if you're dealing with other windows, you'll want to use getmaxyx().